# Removing a class doesn't disable the event listener function associated with the removed class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did a fiddle to *[demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/cc5vtg7g/1)* my problem.

I am having problem to turn off a function activated by a class, any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.changeText').click(function(){
    $(this).html( $(this).html() == 'Test' ? 'Changed' : 'Test' );
  });

  $('.changeBG').click(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
  });

  /* in some cases I need to turn off changeBG function */

  $('.changeBG').removeClass('changeBG');
  // but if you click the div it still turns into red.

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should delegate event to process selector on the fly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could [delegate the event handler](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to a common ancestor.

In doing so, it will only work if that element has that specific class because a check is made when the `click` event is actually fired (rather than when the event handler is attached).

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/tees2v2n/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.changeBG', function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

In the example above, `document` is the common ancestor. Depending on your markup, you will probably want to change that to the closest, constant, ancestor element so that the event isn't fired every time you click on the `document`.

---

Alternatively, you could also use the `.off()` method, and remove that specific event handler by utilizing [event namespaces](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/).

You can attach a specific `click` event named `click.changeBG`:

```
$('.changeBG').on('click.changeBG', function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Then remove that specific event using `.off('click.changeBG')`:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkfv6eL9/)

```
$('.changeBG').removeClass('changeBG').off('click.changeBG');
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar See the example.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Yes. It's called *event delegation*. The click is actually hooked on `document`. You can "root" your event delegation on any element. I usually use the closest common ancestor to the ones that will be being added/removed/changed, rather than `document`, but Josh doesn't have any markup to go on, so... :-)

Comment: Man... I know event delegation, but I didn't expect it would have such an effect too. Wow. `:)` @T.J.Crowder...

Comment: @PraveenKumar: It's fundamental to how delegation works: The click reaches `document`, and then *at that time* jQuery checks to see if it passed through an element matching the delegation selector. So any change you made to the element (or adding a new element entirely) will be reflected, as the check is done when the event occurs.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the handler directly:

```
$('.changeBG').off('click')
```

Note: [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) is jQuery 1.7+, otherwise use `unbind`.

What happens is that the line `$('.changeText').click(...` attaches an handler to all elements with class `changeText`. Removing the class does not remove the handler.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the handler is attached to the element and not the class. The class you referred while attaching is just a filter. You have just changed the class. Not the event that is associated with it:

```
// Do this
$('.changeBG').removeClass('.changeBG').off("click");
```

Or, when you click check for the class:

```
$('.changeBG').click(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass("changeBG"))
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```